# Capture Element not using room from parent control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a page with a capture element and a button overlaid on top to take the picture.

The problem I've got is, the capture element won't use up the whole screen. There are bars above and below.

```
<Grid>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CaptureElement 
            Grid.Row="0"
               x:Name="capPreview"                  
                Stretch="Uniform"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Tapped="capPreview_Tapped"
        />


    <Button Content="Submit"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Grid.Row="1"                          
                      x:Name="btnTakePicture"
                      Click="btnTakePicture_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="100"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </Button.BorderBrush>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**Edit: I have since used the code behind to rotate the capture element, however; upon doing so, the element now just has a box all around it instead of top and bottom.**

```
<CaptureElement 
                Grid.Row="0"
                   x:Name="capPreview"                    
                   Tapped="capPreview_Tapped"
            />
```

Short of hard coding the height and width values, I am out of ideas.

[image: CaptureElement]

Answer (score 1):

It *deos* use the whole screen, the issue is the orientation of the preview is different than the orientation of the screen.

`MediaCapture` has a method `SetPreviewRotation` to handle this issue.

Comment: Is this available on Windows Phone 8.1? My instance of the CaptureElement doesn't have that method available..

Comment: Ah, did you mean the MediaCapture has a method with that name? I've just found it. Thanks.

Comment: Although I found the method, that still doesn't seem to solve my problem. When rotated, there are still huge gaps on every edge of the CaptureElement..

Answer (score 1):

It works for me :) Just grid and Strech, If you want to have focus just make transparent grid outside CaptureElement

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Tapped="SetFocus">
        <CaptureElement x:Name="CaptureElement" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Foreground="Transparent" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" Width="48" Height="48" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Click="OnSaveButtonClicked" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one it will capture directly with the button click

```js
 private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri u = new Uri("ms-data:///local");
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Photo.jpg");

            IRandomAccessStream st = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(st);
            img.Source = image;





        }
```

```html
<CaptureElement Name="element" Height="600"/>
        <StackPanel>
        
            
            <Button Content="Capture Image" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
            
        </StackPanel>
        
        <Image Name="img" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```